# Spring data cassandra CrudRepository save issue : some messages are not getting inserted

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

To insert a message in `Cassandra` Column Family with primary key `messageId` (type: `UUID`) I am using `Spring data` `Cassandra` `CrudRepository` save method. When we run the load with thousands of requests coming per second (2k-3k) with message body size of 40 kb, the save method does not throw any exception. But  while fetching them I observe that some messages are missing in database!

Note: When we use small message body (100 bytes) then we don't observe such problem.

Please suggest how can i resolve this ? Should not i use CrudRepository save method?

OR I just want to know how to know that the save is successful or not ?

Comment: Should i try using @Query instead of save method? Will that make any difference?

Comment: I am using default consistency ONE while reading and writing to Cassandra.  We have a data center with 6 nodes and replication factor 3 in which one node is down.

Comment: The issue is different , I noticed the error  "All host(s) tried for query failed  Connection has been closed) " . Also in stats can see that the write time for few request gone high around 20 seconds. I am looking in to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to consistency level. We were using default consistency level before but later on after setting read and write consistency level to QUORUM the problem got resolved.